# Evitar que se actualicen los datos si no queda stock de productos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trabajo con dos modelos, **Compra** y el otro **Bidon**, desde el formulario **Compras** estoy seleccionando los bidones que tengo disponible en el stock, digamos una cantidad de 100 Bidones, luego de ello, ingreso una nueva cantidad con los bidones que voy a necesitar, digamos 110 bidones, lo que ocurre es que cuando **supero** y guardo la cantidad el Stock de bidones queda con número -10 por ejemplo, lo que quiero lograr es que al intentar guardar el Bidón nuevo, me salte un mensaje o algo que me diga que no puedo utilizar más de los bidones que existen y obviamente evitar que se guarden con valores negativos.

```
class Bidon
  has_many :compras
end

class Compra
  after_save :descontar_bidones

  belongs_to :bidon

  private

  def descontar_bidones
    self.bidon.existencias -= self.cantidad_comprada
    self.bidon.save
  end
end
```

Desde ya muchas gracias y espero me pueda orientar un poco.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es revisar si tu existencia es mayor que tu compra **antes** de llamar a `descontar_bidones`, algo como lo siguiente:

```
class Compra
  before_save :check_stock

  private   
  def check_stock
     unless self.bidon.existencias > self.cantidad_comprada
       errors[:attribute] << "Cantidad a comprar supera existencia"
       return false
     end
  end
end
```

Recuerda que `before_save` se ejecuta después de las validaciones (`validates`), en caso que tengas alguna.

Lo que te dejaría este orden de ejecución:

1. `validates` (si los hay)
2. `before_save` (que verifica si hay existencia de bidones)
3. `after_save` (que descuenta la existencia de bidones)

Comment: Me devuelve: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: NoMethodError in Compras#create a que se debe?

Answer (score 0):

quise adaptar mi código al tuyo solo que yo manejo tres modelos pero espero te sirva, solo agrego un rollback cuando la validación no pase y enviara el error. En tu controller tienes que mandara a llamar check_stock justo despuies de @compra = Compra.new(compra_params) te dejo el codigo.

Model

```
class Compra
  belongs_to :bidon

   def check_stock
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.save
          self.bidon.existencias < self.cantidad_comprada
                errors.add( "Cantidad a comprar supera existencia") 
                raise ActiveRecord::Rollback 
            end
            self.bidon.existencias -= self.cantidad_comprada
            self.bidon.save
           end
        end
      end
    end
```

Controller

```
def create
    @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @compra.check_stock
        format.html { redirect_to @compra, notice: 'Compra was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @compra }
      else
        format.html { render :new  }
        format.json { render json: @compra.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```